# How create a group of agents per time and then operate with separate agents in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Good day!
I have a problem with multiple agents in AnyLogic.
I would like to generate **several agents per time**. It is important that this group of agents has the same Creation time. And it is important to operate the every agent of the group separately. This group should be created by Poisson distribution.

To the best of my knowledge, I have two options for creating the agents:

1. to generate the multiple Agents per arrival in a Source (see pic.1) BUT!
   In this case I have to initially create the population with some quantity of agents. And it seems that AnyLogic doesn't correspond the Agent in the Specific field to the population of agents.
   [image: Picture 1. Source block]

2)to create the empty population and create the agent any time I want.
But in this case I faced with the problem: How to generate several agents per time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re question 2:

Create an event that triggers at some time and in it, create several agents using a for-loop. Simplest case:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    add_MyAgent(); // assumes your agent population is called MyAgent and lives in the same place as the event
    // if your agent type has individual parameters, you can fill them here as well using "add_MyAgent(myFirstParam, mySecondParam...);"
}
```

If you need to create several agents at unique times but want to do this several times, best create a Dynamic Event instead and call that at each time when you want to create a group of agents. Inside it, have the same for loop as above

Answer (score 1):

Create an agent population `myPopulation`, make it initially empty. You can then create any number of agents at any point in time using `add_myPopulation()`, this will add 1 agent to it.

You access individual agents using `myPopulation.get(index)`  with the index number you need.

Instead of using a source, you can start a flow chart with an Enter block and put your agents into it at any time using `myEnterBlock.take(agent)`.

Sounds like you should study some more of the bsics, do all the tutorials in the AL help to understand more of the principles of populations, agents, flow charts...

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand when I create several agents per time these agents are also included in the population and I can get them later. However if I try to check the myPopulation.size() after creation these agents it is empty.

From the other side, I understand that I can generate the agents whenever I want. I can't understand how to create several agents with the same timestamp. The only option I see is to use Source with generation agents per time.

Comment: if `myPopulation.size()==0` after agent creation, you did not create the agents for that population. Use `add_myPopulation()` to create an agent and add it to that pop. Timestamps is not an AnyLogic concept, so you need to store their creation time yourself

Comment: I am sorry for misundertanding. I read a lot, but in most cases there are no any interpretation of creating several agents per time. I edit the question and I tried to make it more clear...